# Crash in Firebase auth v2 -> v3 migration code

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have some code I put in my react-native app a couple of years ago to support the forced migration of users from v2 -> v3 authentication. I am using the Web version of Firebase (6.6.0) in my app (NOT `react-native-firebase`).

I recently had a user try to log in with an old v2 token found in AsyncStorage (local storage). The app crashed with the following error:

```
 TypeError · undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new t.default.Promise')
```

The crash occured on [this line](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-auth-migration-helpers/blob/41156ebb684af8d6a269cba9c23ea804a4685e12/web/migrate.js#L76) of the migration code supplied by Firebase. I'm guessing this migration code is no longer supported and I should just remove it from my app. But what should I do instead if a person tries to log in with a saved V2 auth token? Can she simply log out and log in again? Or does she have to change her password? Or does she have to create a new account, losing her old data?.

I don't have a way to replicate this situation since I have no way of logging in to v2 authentication. So I would appreciate a clarification from the Firebase team. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; I've decided to remove the migration code from my app. When someone fires up the app and a legacy token is loaded from AsyncStorage, I simply delete the token and present the user with a login page.

I corresponded with Firebase auth support and include their answers below. First off, they suggested changing `firebase.Promise` in the code to `Promise` as firebase.Promise doesn't exist any more. This fixed the crash. Then, to test, I found an old simulator image that still had a legacy token in its AsyncStorage. Working with that, I found that the response to the `XMLHttpRequest` to the `exchangeToken` endpoint result in a null response (after approximately one minute). This tells me the endpoint is dead and there is no point in trying to query it, thus it makes sense to remove the migration code altogether from my app (even if the endpoint were working, a 2-year-old token surely would have expired.)

Then the question is what to do to enable users in this situation to upgrade gracefully. Firebase support suggested I should export the user (I have quite a few but I don't have a way to identify them definitively), then delete the user and import again. I couldn't believe all that hassle was necessary so I managed to find a couple of friends with old accounts. They had both forgotten their passwords, but after resetting, they were able to log in easily. So based on this limited testing, I think all that is necessary is to have them log in again. If that doesn't work they can contact our support and we'll go from there.

EMAILS FROM FIREBASE SUPPORT

> I understand you, it must be a very frustrating situation, let’s try to find a solution together. I have checked your case and, as you have mentioned, the library is no longer actively maintained, so I’ll escalate your case to our engineering team in order to get any suggestions for your case, please wait a little until they can answer us.

> The engineering team has answered and, unfortunately, they have said that old auth tokens have been unsupported for a long time, they suggested you forked the library and try to change firebase.Promise(), which does not exist anymore and then convert that to Promise(), but they can guess other errors will pop up and probably you will need to fix the code.
> Thanks a lot for the clarification, I’m so sorry for my misunderstanding. If you want to delete the migration helper, as a workaround, you can export all the users (or only the users having the old token, if you have identified them), delete the users and import them again. This process will re-create the user and it will have the auth latest version because the user would be like a new user, with the same credentials and authentication methods. After that, the user on his side, needs to update the application, log out and log in again in order to update the token.

> Please try to do the described workaround with a specific and identified user to limit the scope in case of fail and let me know how it goes.

> Nice to hear from you again! Yes, the users will have the same UID and password, as you can see Auth export, the format contains those data and a lot of other more. Unfortunately, based on this, there is no way to know which of the accounts have an old auth token, so, in order to do a test and error approach, I suggest you try to do this with one user (identified old auth token user) to minimize unwanted results.